# Using "sudo dd if=/dev/urandom bs=16M of=/dev/sdx", why do I still have a partition left on the device, and has the device been overwritten 100%?

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount

I used the above command: `sudo dd if=/dev/urandom bs=16M of=/dev/sdx`, and when it completed, there was still a partition on the micro-sd.

However, when I try to mount the micro-sd, it will not mount, instead, I get the error message: `mount: /media: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on dev/sdxx, missing code page or helper program, or other error`

This only happens about 10% of the time when I use this command with a micro-sd card reader.

I am not able to mount it to any other place either (ie: /mnt).

I wonder if it has been cleaned or I need to redo it using the same command... I usually re-clean it until there is no partition left, which has always been 1 extra cleaning.

**UPDATE**:

```
**output** - 16GB micro-sd
1.. MAJ:MIN = 8:48, 8:49
2.. DISK = 14.9GB (disk), 14.7GB (part)
3.. error message: mount: /media: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on dev/sdxx, missing code page or helper program, or other error
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
1.. "partprobe -ds /dev/sdxx" = "msdos partitions"
2.. "partprobe /dev/sdxx" = partitions 1-64 on /dev/sdxx, but can not inform kernel of change since likely in use.......
```

Comment: First guess is that there is 1 chance in 10 that the output of /dev/urandom looks like a valid partition table of some kind, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Include the output that's showing the partition table. Why did you choose a block size of 16 MB? It's unlikely that your SD card has 16 MB blocks.

Comment: Do you try to mount just after `dd`? or after reboot/reinsert/`partprobe`?

Comment: Get familiar with `wipefs`.

Comment: @Seth Someone a while back gave me the command with "bs=16M" in it; only reason.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I scrub sd with dd command. I look at lsblk to see if the partition has been wiped. If not, I take out of card reader, disconnect card reader, reconnect it, then put sd back in and check it again (same results). I'll take a look at "wipefs" - only familiar with wipe. It seems "wipe" takes a long time to run; I have used it on directories before. Never heard of "partproble" - will take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Will "wipefs" erase part of the filesystem, and if so, do I want to do that 'now'? "wipefs does not erase the whole filesystem or any other data from the device." -- https://linux.die.net/man/8/wipefs

Comment: Yes, `wipefs` only erases signatures. If randomly generated (or any) partition table bothers you and you want it gone, call `wipefs` after `dd`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks. I'm assuming it doesn't just remove the partition, but it wipes the partition in the process...? I (think I know) with 'fdisk' that it deletes a partition, but does not seem to wipe it. So, 'wipefs' will effectively do the same thing as "dd...urandom" command, except it will be specific to the partition that I mark for wipefs. Do I understand correctly? Thanks.

Comment: No. `wipefs` removes *signatures*. It can remove a partition table (if any, sane or not); it doesn't wipe the whole disk/partition. Your problem seems to be there is a (random? by chance?) partition table you don't want. `wipefs` will make sure there is none.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Well, more so than there being a partition table that i don't want, the bigger issue is when there is a partition table, knowing whether or not the sd was scrubbed (or not). I can delete the partition in 10 seconds with fdisk, so that doesn't matter. I am just concerned when i see a partition that 'possibly' the sd has not been scrubbed, or, not scrubbed properly.